# Should I learn Maya because it is superior to Blender in animation?

Tags: animation, rigging

I have been studying Blender for more than 3 years, I am really in love with it, but I want to concentrate more on rigging and animation, but I am struggling and it's very hard in Blender, and people suggest Maya for rigging and animation. 
But I don't know nothing about Maya, should I start learning that also, is it possible to learn both?

Also what do you think, how good is Maya compared to Blender in animation?

Please advice me, friends.

Comment: *"...and it's very hard in Blender"* - Give an example of what do you mean by that. Suggest ask a question specifically about your issue and we'll see "how hard" that really is...

Comment: It will not be easier in Maya. Maya is even more complex. It has some more mature functionality, but it also has so much stuff that just doesn't work. It crashes a lot in comparison especially if we are talking about rigging. It is old and full of features and sometimes that's great but sometimes that's also a problem, because old features must be maintained because they are integrated in some workflows of large studios, and often that leads to bugs and things not working together with newer features.

Comment: It would be interesting to ask the opposite question on Maya forums "Should I learn Blender because it's superior to Maya in animation?" :D

Comment: @brockmann by hard i mean, I have been studying and studying but got no results, there are so many tutorials on youtube, but couldn't find someone who starts from beginning to advanced, in modeling we have blenderguru, but in rigging i find no one, so i am stuck.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys do you know of some great tutorials, whether free or paid, or any book.

Comment: Nathan Vegdahl's free youtube full course Human Rigging, then DanPro and LevePixelLevel.

Comment: @joshsanfelici thanks a lot, the tutorials that you mentioned are amazing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question might seem opinion based and therefore not suitable for this platform and I think it actually might be the case. However, I think it is possible to answer it based on facts, or maybe I should say the absence of facts that you should learn Maya instead of Blender or that one of them is superior in animation as a whole.

I can say with certainty that there are no rules or laws that would force you to learn any 3d software instead of another. Blender is free so you definitely do not have any restrictions choosing it instead of any other package. It has all the tools to make animations, and there are studios that use it even for animated feature films and they seem to be happy with Blender instead of Maya. [Tangent Labs](https://www.tangent-labs.com/) with their [Next Gen](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7133686/) is a famous great example.

I think the answer to your question is: no, you shouldn't, meaning you can but do not have to. You can choose whatever you wish.